# get(url) loading url then rerouting?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm using some code to dictate what environment I want tests to run in, when I execute the test it's loading the correct URL however it is then auto-rerouting to qa1. I've confirmed it's something specific to the code, am I overlooking something here that could be causing this?

BeforeTest where it's occurring

```java
/**
* This function will execute before each Test tag in testng.xml
* @param browser
* @throws Exception
*/

@BeforeTest
@Parameters({"browser", "environmentURL"})
public void setup(String browserName, String env) {
            
    logg.info("Initializing browser setup");
    logg.info(browserName + " Session has started");
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")){
    //create firefox instance
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
        //set path to chromedriver.exe
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
        //create chrome instance
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    //Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")){
        //set path to Edge.exe
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "/usr/local/bin/msedgedriver");
        //create Edge instance
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
    }

    logg.info("Waiting for browser to load");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);             
    logg.info("Maximizing window");      
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    if(env.equals("qa1")){
        logg.info("Opening QA1 environment");
        driver.get("https://connect.qa1.website.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else if(env.equals("qa2")){
        logg.info("Opening QA2 environment");
        driver.get("https://connect.qa2.website.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else if(env.equals("qa3")){
        logg.info("Opening QA3 environment");
        driver.get("https://connect.qa3.website.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }       
}
```

testng if needed:

```xml
<test name="ChromeTest">
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
<parameter name="environmentURL" value="qa3"/>
<classes>
    <class name="tests.LoginTests">
    </class>
</classes>
</test>
```

Comment: you need to include more code.  There's nothing there that would cause a re-direct, though I'd get rid of the else/ifs.  Just use case/switch or standard if thens.  No need for else in this case.

Comment: for instance, show where "env" is defined.  There's a parameter name called "environmentURL" but you don't show how that becomes "env".

Comment: @pcalkins I added the rest of the code for that method, I can def get rid of the else ifs!

Comment: doesn't seem like there's a problem here...  (though you only need to set implicitwait once... it's globally set for the session..)  What shows in the log?  Also if you output "env" what does that say?  You need to find out if it reaches each .get()...   are you sure this isn't server-side or even a hosts file thing?

Comment: OR, there's another .get() used in your test methods... make sure you click to navigate from here, or set a "baseURL" to use going forward.

Comment: I removed the other implicitwaits just now, added in the outputs and it seems fine. I'm exploring the possibility of another .get() being used now. I appreciate the help!